# Is there some technology that can be used to read program-related custom file, and then manage cutom data like Memory Database？

Tags: database, uitableview, user-interface, user-input, custom-data-type

Even I can use Sql statement with CRUD.In this case, I can show some data to UI easily by some specific change condition. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of research, I find some method. In Linux We can use MongoDB + memory-mapped file, such as tmpfs in Linux. Guide is here, [English original](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/49304254688/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis) and [Chinese Translation](https://www.oschina.net/translate/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis-style?print).

But this is a bit troublesome when relating to Windows, which need help of some tool. If so, that's unnecessary. Write your own file helper honestly manage your data (also for me).